# Django ModelChoiceField initial value is not showing up while editting

Tags: django

I have an form "ModelChoiceField" form field, and when adding the data it works fine ! But how to retrieve the saved data database to get selected when the form is edited ?

```
form = AddForm(owner=pk, instance=data, initial={'course': data.course})
```

I even tried setting initial value, but still am not getting to selected value to get displayed !

```
class AddForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, owner, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['course'].queryset = Faculty.objects.filter(owner=owner)
```

And note, that the selected values are correctly getting saved on database ! But its not showing up

Comment: Can you make sure if the parameter `owner` is what you think it is? It might be None. and it might be in kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `owner` from the kwargs like in the example below.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    owner = kwargs.pop('owner')
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['course'].queryset = Faculty.objects.filter(owner=owner)
```